# Вывести элемент двумерного массива

Tags: массивы, php

Имеется двумерный массив. Нужно вывести оценки Петрова.

```
<?php
    $ocenki = array(
                    "Иванов" => array ("алгебра - 4 ", "химия - 5 ", "Литература - 3"),
                    "Петров" => array ("алгебра - 3 ", "химия - 3 ", "Литература - 5"),
                    "Сидоров" => array ("алгебра - 5 ", "химия - 3 ", "Литература - 4")
                    );
    echo  $ocenki[1];
?>
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так. Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: @Frip, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас индекса 1 не существует. Это ассоциативный массив. Нужно обращаться через ключи-названия:

```
$ocenki["Петров"];
```

Но этого недостаточно. В `$ocenki["Петров"]` будет содержаться еще один массив. А чтобы вывести этот массив, нужно пробежаться по нему любым из циклов. Удобнее всего через цикл foreach, который, по сути, и предназначен для перебора массива. В итоге код будет таким:

```
$ocenki = array (
     "Иванов" => array ("алгебра - 4 ", "химия - 5 ", "Литература - 3"),
     "Петров" => array ("алгебра - 3 ", "химия - 3 ", "Литература - 5"),
     "Сидоров" => array ("алгебра - 5 ", "химия - 3 ", "Литература - 4")
);

foreach ($ocenki["Петров"] as $ocenka) {
    echo $ocenka."<br />";
}
```